# How to remove custom-css from Wordpress Database

Tags: css, wordpress, jetpack

I installed jetpack a while ago, but decided to uninstall and delete it. I was using the custom-css feature that it came with to style my site.

However, even after uninstalling it and deleting it the custom css I entered is still being loaded on my site. I did some research and this is because the custom css is stored in the database.

How can I remove this css from the database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will be the same for you according to the theme you use but for me it was that:
In functions/theme-head.php through Appearance > Editor, comment this line:
`echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'. THEME_URI .'/css/custom.css?ver='.THEME_VERSION.'" media="all" />'."\n";`